# Как добавить умным указателям в C++ дополнительный адрес

Tags: c++, указатели, c++11, память

Есть процессор ARM с дополнительными аппаратными модулями для ускорения отдельных операций. Проблема в том, что они требуют два адреса для работы: виртуальный и физический. При выделении и освобождении памяти они выдаются парой:

```
uint64_t phyaddr;
void *   virtaddr;

// Выделим 100500 байт
hw_alloc(&phyaddr, &virtaddr, 100500);

// скопируем откуда-то через DMA
dma_copy(phyaddr, virtaddr, phyaddr2, virtaddr2);

// освободим память
hw_free(phyaddr, virtaddr);
```

Хотелось бы хранить оба этих адреса в одном объекте и, при этом, пользоваться умными указателями. Можно ли как-то штатным образом расширить или переопределить их, чтобы добавить поле с физическим адресом, аллокатор и деаллокатор через подобные сишные функции?
Чтобы оно могло быть хотя бы каким-то таким:

```
shared_hw_ptr<obj> ptr = make_shared_hw<obj>();
dma_copy(ptr->get(), ptr->getphy(), phyaddr2, virtaddr2);
```

Comment: объединить  `uint64_t phyaddr; void *   virtaddr;` в структуру и хранить указатель на нее, возможно

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не создавать лишний оверхед и не тратить память на хранение указателя на структуру, придется раздобыть исходники std::shared_ptr | qniqie_ptr и написать свое, подсматривая в них.